# Change the place of page numbering from footer to top right of the header

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I am working on this [template for thesis](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/neu-ece-thesis) <sup>linked to sharelatex.com</sup>. I want to change the place of page numbering from center of the footer to top right of the header.

I read [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Customizing_Page_Headers_and_Footers) that changing `\pagestyle` from `{plain}` to `{myheadings}` would do the job. However, even changing all of the `\pagestyles`, I had no luck.

I also surfed through the community and came across using `fancyhdr` package but could not figure out how to implement it here.

Comment: I did not take a look at the template (I hesitate to download extern stuff to answer questions here). Try `\usepackage{fancyhdr}\pagestyle{fancy}\rhead{\thepage}\cfoot{}`.

Comment: Where are you calling `\pagestyle`? For me, 
`\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{myheadings}

\begin{document}
content
\end{document}`

compiles with the page number top-right.

Comment: @DanielLittlewood Yeah, that's what I used to do. But here it's not that simple as the template is much more complicated than an article.

Comment: @Skillmon tried it with no luck. I think the problem is that somewhere that gets overwritten. And I cannot find where!

Comment: Try `\usepackage{fancyhdr}\AtBeginDocument{\pagestyle{fancy}\rhead{\thepage}\cfoot{}}`.

Comment: @Skillmon Thanks, but still not doing anything. Cheers.

Comment: Do you use a `\mainmatter` somewhere? If so, try using the `\pagestyle...` part after `\mainmatter`(or after any formatting changing command for the section you'd like it in). This is not a clean solution, I admit, but I will not look at the code. My guessing ends here for that reason.

Comment: @Skillmon I am using front matter to have different styles (roman and arabic) and used your suggestion at the very end but no, it ain't working. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Skillmon Thanks for your help. I was able to find a workaround with `fancyhdr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this template I have found a work around which is not a clean solution but works for now.

In order to move the page-numbering to the desired place (generally modifying header and footer) `fancyhdr` is a powerful package. What I did was changing the `\pagestyle` for each section using that package; however, you will see that first page of each section still has the page number in `\cfoot`. To overcome that, you need to redefine `fancypagestyle{plain}`. Look below for an example;

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  % you need to include this in the macro so it will be
                       % used for the whole document


% to remove all the headers and footers:
\pagestyle{empty} 

 % change the page-numbering style for all the pages 
 % without section name:
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}


 % change the page-numbering style for the page 
 % with section name:    
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
}

%Example document:
\title{Example}
\author{Masoud}
\date{June 2018}

\begin{document}


\maketitle


\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]